# Javascript - relative path incorrect?

Tags: javascript, path, relative-path

I'm trying to use "easy-comment" however struggling with the relative path it's setting.

I'd have thought the first line would set the directory so that the second mention of the path would assume it was in the same place.. but clearly not!

Can anyone help?

setup: running easy comment on a separate site to the site this code is on

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.anotherwebsite.co.uk/easycomment/jquery.easy-comment.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my-comment,#your-comment,#is-this-ok-comment,#news-ting").EasyComment({
    path:"/easycomment/",
    moderate:true,
    maxReply:5
  });
});
      </script>
```

I've tried adding the full http:// for the second mention of the path but it errors with

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://anotherwebsite.co.uk/easycomment/ec-comment.php. Origin http://www.thiswebsite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Cross domain AJAX is not allowed

Comment: If you have control on the distant server (http://www.anotherwebsite.co.uk domain) you can set the http header to accept the requests from your first domain, else you cannot : its forbidden.

Comment: Thanks Ricola, could you give me an example of how to implement that please? sorry this is all new to me

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

now added however I'm getting this error:

GET http://www.anotherwebsite.co.uk/easycomment/jquery.easy-comment.js 500 (Internal Server Error) history-of-bristol.html:18
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'EasyComment'

Answer (score 0):

cross domain ajax is not allowed.

if you want to test it anyway you can disable websecurity in chrome.

but you should change the path to an resource on your server

Comment: The server I'm wanting it to run on cannot run PHP - any ideas to get this working cross domain or is it a 100% no?

Comment: do don't need necessarily PHP on your server, maybe you can use a different technology on your server.

Comment: Do you have access to your server? because then you could install PHP

Comment: Its a lotus domino server so it'd be easier to allow cross browser access - however adding allow origin doesnt seem to be working in the htaccess even though its adding to the head ok its not allowing it